# xlsxwriter catch an error before workbook.close()

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have a script that saves 10 worksheets to an .xlsx using xlsxwriter.
When I try to close the worksheet, I get an error:

```
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)".
```

I try to catch the error when I write the lines to the sheet but without any success. As a result, my worksheet doesn't get saved at all and I can't handle with the exception for the line.

Here is my code-

```
def xlsx_writer(name, data):
    worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet(name)
    line_number = 0
    for line in data:
        try:
            worksheet1.write_row(line_number, 0, line)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            line = [x.decode('utf-8') for x in line]
            worksheet1.write_row(line_number, 0, line)
```

How can I catch the error while writing every line and not when I close the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I catch the error while writing every line and not when I close the workbook?

In short, you can't. The error occurs when writing non ASCII or UTF-8 encoded data out to the target file and that doesn't happen until the file is closed.

If you just want to avoid this error then just decode() your data before passing it to `write()` or `write_row()`.